# Persist state after reload in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, persistence, reload

Once I go to a particular page by passing in props to that page I want to be able to reload the page without losing the state, currently, when I reload, the page throws an error, that the prop is missing.
For example if I use

`history.push({ pathname: '/animal-details',animal_id: animal.id })`
it shows the details on these next page but when I reload the page the data goes away and the page is left blank. How to get around this?
Thank You.

Comment: `history.push(\`history.push` this looks like a typo?

Comment: Persisting state between page reloads is usually done through cookies and local/session storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from using localStorage or cookies, I think this is a good situation to just make the `animal_id` part of the path.

Instead of doing

```
history.push({ pathname: '/animal-details',animal_id: animal.id })
```

I would do:

```
history.push(`/animal-details/${animal.id}`)
```

using a template literal.

If you're using `react-router-dom`, you can get the animal id using the `location` prop or the `useLocation` hook.

```
const path = props.location.pathname.split('/')
const animalId = path[path.length - 1] // the animal id is the last value in the array
```

If you aren't using `react-router-dom` for whatever reason, you can also do something similar using vanilla js `window.location.href`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

1. **localStorage**

```js
localStorage.getItem('yourData');
```

or

2. **Cookies**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie